# ffmpeg - DF vs NDF (Drop Frames) vs (Non Drop Frames), how to simply pass input timecode to output

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, ffprobe, timecodes, .mov

Please help with this issue. The broadcaster just rejected my submitted video because their validation tool threw this kind of error:

> was configured as "Non drop Frame". "Drop Frame" expected.

I'm only processing video, and I expect the audio to just be copied from input to output.
Running and comparing input with output using **ffprobe** shows difference in **timecode**:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-02-29T22:07:42.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:20.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 133935 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dvvideo (dvh6 / 0x36687664), yuv422p(bt709, top coded first (swapped)), 1280x1080 [SAR 3:2 DAR 16:9], 115084 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-29T22:07:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : DVCPRO HD 1080i60
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-29T22:07:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-29T22:07:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-29T22:07:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
```

After video conversion, the output of ffprobe:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.58.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 167037 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (XQ) (ap4x / 0x78347061), yuv422p12le(tv, bt709, top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080, 148578 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.106.100 prores_ks
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
```

My encoding string looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf scale=1920x1080 -map 0:v? -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:d? -b:v 115084915 -maxrate 115084915 -minrate 115084915 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 5 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -c:a copy -c:s copy -y output.mov
```

Please help!

Comment: I just added: `-map_metadata 0`    and the output carried creation_time correctly. Just not the timecode, which is what I need.